# Draw lines and make them intersecting with each other

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get the center of cauliflower  by using the main veins of its leaves as you can see in this image: http://labs.tineye.com/color/4af1de43259507087d771efcda5babe3bd84c3cf?ignore_background=True&width=250&color_format=hex&ignore_interior_background=True&height=158

So, is there any  possible way to draw lines by using these main veins and get the intersection point for them (might be the center of the cauliflower)?

I  have tried the Hough Line Transform and did detect the lines (main veins) ,but I couldn't extend the lines and make them intersecting with each other.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you obtain the main line using Hough line transform, why don't you mathematically compute their intersections. For each pair of lines, you compute the intersection, then you can take the average point of all intersections.

Comment: can you provide lossless compressed (e.g. png) full resolution image?

Comment: You can compute the slope of each line and compute (mathematical) the intersection of each 2 lines. At the end there might be some clusters of intersections, which might correspond to your cauliflower center.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .I'll try that and let you know, but I still need how gets lines intersect (how to implement it in opencv visual c++).

Comment: thats more a question about mathematics than programming?!?

Comment: Assuming you used the probabilistic version of the Hough transform in opencv. You obtain for each line a point and a vector. You extract the line equation from that. And then from two lines equations, you compute their intersection.

Comment: Yes,here is the Hough transform :http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: I am using the probabilistic Hough transform. So just wanna how to start from the point and vector for each line?

Comment: YesI know the slope equation:
The slope= (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
m= ((y1- slope* x1)+(y2-slope*x2))*0.5,but still dont know how to use it to extend the lines till the intersection point.Yes, I've  got the idea but how to implement it in opencv .Actually ,I am still learning this language . 
I will be very thankful for any help .